# How to open MiKTeX console from terminal in Linux?

Tags: miktex

I am using Linux and trying install some packages for my LaTeX files. When I google, people say that we should open MiKTeX first, but I don't know how to open it! Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you are running miktex on linux (it is possible but rather unusual, almost all tex users on linux use texlive)

Comment: Might just be called mpm, though not sure if there is a gfx interface for the miktex console on Linux. Other than that, I'd also use texlive on Linux instead.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, I have texlive not miktex. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are running miktex on linux? (it is possible but rather unusual, almost all tex users on linux use texlive)